# truncated linear congruential generator

Tags: cryptanalysis, lattice-crypto

I'm trying to reverse a truncated linear congruential generator with all parameters ( modulus  $M,$ multiplier $a$, addend $b$ and the seed $x_0$) hidden.

I have read Scott Contini's article *On Stern's attack against truncated linear congruential generator*. His method on finding the modulus is easy to apply if $k = 64$ or more ($k$ is the number of bits in $M$).

I know I'm missing something so can someone please help? Given the following truncated sequence how do I reverse it. $y_i  =   9, 7, 25, 14, 16, 3, 8, 18, 0, 6, 10, 10, \ldots$.

The hidden parameters are $M= 1009, a=167 ,b=63,  k =10$. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.